# Prevent Azure from shutting down my App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am running a .NET Core web application on an Azure App Service (App Service plan is configured to use S1). It is stable.

However, I recently ran an automated test against production and it caused 100s of errors in a few minutes. After this, the App Service became unavailable for a long time.

I know that App Service basically uses IIS and I know that there is a setting in IIS that will shut down an App Service on too many errors in a short time. I am assuming that this is the setting that came into effect for my app.

My question is: How do I prevent Azure from shutting down my App Service, even if many errors happen in a short time?

Comment: I frequently aborted threads in my application. Once I removed this, it has not happened, so it is a reasonable guess of the underlying reason.

Answer (score 6):

Investigate the "Always On" setting that can be changed in the Azure Portal under Application settings, General Settings. This value is configured per App.

The UI control will be disabled if your price tier does not support always on. Typically these lower priced levels in the pricing tiers are not used for a production site.

Comment: These things take some time to test because I have to wait for the next event. I did change that setting, but the same problem occurred again this night. A restart of the app service "fixed" it.

Answer (score 0):

> I recently ran an automated test against production and it caused 100s of errors in a few minutes. After this, the App Service became unavailable for a long time.

Firstly, you can [enable diagnostic functionality for App Service web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) to log information from both the web server and the web application, which will help you troubleshoot the issue.

Secondly, you can try to [increase the number of instances that run your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-scale) and check if it can mitigate the issue.

Besides, if possible, you can [set up staging environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing) and do automated test on staging environment instead of production environment, which will not cause your production shutting down for long time when you do automated test on staging.

Comment: About increasing the number of instances, I can predict that this would not solve anything, but in best case make it less likely of happening. I want to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: About setting up a staging environment, I am running this against production purposefully because I want to use it for monitoring that goes a little deeper than just a simple ping. So it has to run against production.

Comment: About enabling diagnostics, I have done this, but there is nothing in the diagnostics. Only the errors that I myself provoked are there, and there is no mystery about them, they are real errors and that is OK. The issue is that the App Service became unresponsive after these errors occurred and then nothing is logged in the diagnostics.

Comment: @Niels: Is it possible that your automation test exceeds a fair usage threshold on another service such as an Azure database. For example the DocumentDb api incorporates automatic back-off and retry logic when requests per second exceed request units purchased.

Comment: In short: No. Then the app would be responsive but return errors. The app was not responding at all. Also Application Insights reported that the app was offline. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this problem was correctly diagnosed back in 2017 when I was using a .NET Core WebApp. Maybe it was or maybe it wasn't.

However, I have today in late 2019 on Azure Functions V2 and .NET Core 2.2 recreated the same scenario and provoked 5000 unhandled exceptions in one minute and the Function did not go down because of that.

So anyone finding this question can pretty much rest assured, if they are on Azure Functions V2 or newer - it does not crash just because of the quantity of exceptions like it was the case with default settings in IIS in the past.